# Pandas rolling apply custom functions that return ndarrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rolling-computation

Say I have a DataFrame whose index is time and I want to compute one ndarray for each time window in a rolling manner. How can I do this using `pandas`'s `rolling` functionality?

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.period_range('2018-01-01', periods=100, freq='D'),
    columns=range(3),
    data=np.random.randn(100, 3)
)


def custom_func(sub_df: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    # do something, return a matrix
    # fora minimal example, return sub_df.T @ sub_df
    # the real task is much more complicated...
    return sub_df.T @ sub_df

# can I apply custom_func using rolling?
# the return should be a 3D numpy array
# like
# resarray = df.rolling(window=5).apply(custom_func)
```

Comment: "ValueError: Of the three parameters: start, end, and periods, exactly two must be specified" Please fix.

Comment: @coldspeed edited, thanks.

Comment: Your dot product returns scalar values. How will this result in a 3D array? Your code works for this data.

Comment: @coldspeed sub_df is matrix with shape = (5, 3), so sub_df.T @ sub_df will return a 3 by 3.

Comment: @coldspeed also, my `custom_func` is just for illustration, the real task is do PCA on sub_df...